# angularJs ui grid columns widths are not adjusted automatically

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular ui-grid and trying to assign data dynamically. this is working fine but its column width is not proper. 
Code is given below

```
$http({
method: 'POST',
url: 'controllers.php?action=execQuery',
data: {'queryStr': $scope.queryStr,'dbName': $scope.selectDatabase},
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
$scope.myData.data = data;
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
});
```

please refer the blow image

http://pasteboard.co/bTPt5SA.png

Comment: <div id="grid1" ui-grid="myData" class="grid"  ui-grid-auto-resize></div>

Comment: earlier i was using <div id="grid1" ui-grid="myData" class="grid"  ></div>

Answer (score 0):

ok you have left all the options customization, and that give you this behaviour.
e.s.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  enableColumnResizing: true,
  columnDefs: [
    { field: 'name' },
    { field: 'gender', enableColumnResizing: false },
    { field: 'company' }
  ]
};
```

rather then auto-resize. In this option you can even write all rows and column in html.

take a look here.
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/204_column_resizing
and here

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/wiki/Configuration-Options